# Add css a:hover dynamically in VB code behind

Tags: java, css

depending on what data I retrieve from the database, I need to update the color of a menu item. This is no problem for me, device.Style.Add("background-color", "red") works just fine for me. However, when I change the background color, it overrides my CSS style sheet, which is supposed to change the color to light grey on a:hover. Is there a way to update what the a:hover background color should be in my VB code? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use vb to attach a css class to the button. Then style that class to have the color you want.